# Alternatives to relay to conditioning a circuit

Tags: power, conditioning

I got a "problem" and it is because of my lack of knowledge so I need your help.

First, the current design is like the attached below this paragraph. The power comes from a car battery (24v or 12v), then I power a DC-DC Converter `T1` and this the my `IC`. So the converter `T1` has a pull up pin, internally, `EN` that enables the converter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2UkNZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What I want to achieve is when the car turns on, turning the key, the circuit powers up and when the cars shuts down, the circuit too. In my design I'm using a relay NO with the key contact and the battery on the coil and a GND on the common pin of the relay, on NO the `EN` pin and NC not connected.

The key contact has 12 or 24v depending the battery.

The problem I got is the relay for 12 or 24V usually is a "Relay cube" that it is big (19mm x 15mm). I saw solid state relay for 3.3 or less voltage that are very small but for this I need another dc-dc converter just to drive this relay and this is more messy.

What will be an improvement for this circuit? A transistor?, but I don't know what kind because the specs for the voltage from base to emitter are low (base 24/12v to 0v) Or are there a some IC for this use case?

On a second iteration of the design I will have another event (key contact and IC pin) so I will need some logic gate for drive the `EN` pin. Just to know if there is a better implementation.

Comment: You have bigger problems than your relay, if you're using a transformer there. You need a DC-DC converter; transformers *only* work with AC.

Comment: @Hearth: Obviously, it IS a DC-DC converter. Magnetic transformers don't have an "enable pin".

Comment: Why don't you permanently enable your "transformer" and connect it to a power source (usually called "Accessory") that is switched on and off with the ignition?

Comment: Just connect EN to the key, why the relay?  Most DCDC the enable is active high with an internal pull-down.

Comment: Don't need a DC-DC converter to drive it, a zener and a resistor should probably be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I missnamed the component it is a dc-dc converter, my bad. The EN pin has a pull up internally, I already told in the question, so to shuts it down I have to connect it to ground. I guess the problem is than in the draw the ~EN seems EN

Comment: @Cristobol Polychronopolis, I guess you mean to put the zener and the resistor to the base, but this will draw some power, no? Just to reduce de voltage. Thanks